# Android map overlay exact coordinates

Tags: android, dictionary, overlay

I am putting an image as an overlay on an Android google map.  Does the image appear aligning the origin of the image at the coordinates?  Is there a way to control it?  If I want the center of the image to be at the overlay coordinates how do I go about?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//This will make the center of the image to be at the coordinates.

public abstract class CustomOverlay<Item extends OverlayItem> extends ItemizedOverlay<Item> {

public CustomOverlay(Drawable defaultMarker, MapView mapView) {
    super(boundCenter(defaultMarker), mapView); 
    .
    .
    .

}
```

Comment: Thank you.  It works perfect.  One thing I noticed is that the boundCenter works only for the default marker.  If I change the marker using overlayitem.setMarker(anotherImage); the image is aligned at (0,0).  Thank you very mcuh. It resolved my issue.